# Как отменить действие -webkit-appearance: none для конкретного selecta?

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть общее `css` свойство, которое отменяет `-webkit-appearance: none;` для всех тегов, что влияет на отображение стрелочек в теге `select`.

Вопрос: как вернуть стрелочку в конкретном `select` ?

`-webkit-appearance: unset;` не работает...

```css
* {
-webkit-appearance: none; 
}
.select {
-webkit-appearance: unset; 
}
```

```html
<select class="select"><option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `-webkit-appearance: menulist;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По умолчанию `-webkit-appearance` для select - `menulist`. Следовательно его и вставляйте.

```css
* {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.select {
  -webkit-appearance: menulist;
}
```

```html
<select class="select">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```